# Convert sqlite3 .dmp file to .sql or to .db

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Good day. I have a .zip file of a .dmp that was from a sqlite3 .db file. I used the instructions in [this tutorial](http://ingenious-camel.blogspot.com/2012/02/deploy-sqlite-database-on-android.html) to get the .zip file. However, my laptop crashed and I was only able to recover the .zip file.

I was able to unzip the file, however, I am clueless on how to open the .dmp file and convert it to a .sql or a .db file.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I am dumbfounded and I am not sure how to go about this problem that I have, I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote of a year old question with a working solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dmp file has been generated using the .dump command which dumps the database in an SQL text format. So the file already has SQL which can be used to generate the .db. Use the read command of sqlite shell.

See https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: Thanks. I opened the dmp file in a text editor and it's raw sql statements, thanks.